# How many load states of Titanium video player's have and the meanings each of them?

Tags: titanium, video-player

guys! I need your help! Recently, I'm trying to add the ***[loadstate](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer)*** event listener to the video player, however, when I'm console the event ***evt*** to check the load state I found there're different kinds in **IOS** and **Android** platform and unexpected, the state meanings are different too. As far as I known,

1. Android load states video player only have two kinds: **0** and **1**

   ① the **0** load state seems like **preloading**

   ② the **1** load state seems like can **play normally**
2. IOS load states of video player have four kinds: **1**, **2**, **3** and **5**

   I only know that the state **5** comes when the network is not connect

Here is my code:

```
var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
    visible: false,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    message: 'loading...'
});

videoPlayer.addEventListener('loadstate', function(evt){
    console.info('---------load state---------');
    console.info(evt.loadState);

    if(evt.loadState == 5){
        activityIndicator.show();
    }
});
```

I had checked the **API**, however there's no answer. Anyone of you have a good knowledge about it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome.

--**EDITED**--

OK, maybe I misunderstood the question, sorry. In the latest version of Titanium SDK, the API talks with the native iOS class `MPMoviePlayerController`, then you can check the loadState directly in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieLoadState)

```
enum {
   MPMovieLoadStateUnknown        = 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlayable       = 1 << 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK  = 1 << 1,
   MPMovieLoadStateStalled        = 1 << 2,
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieLoadState;
```

Also, you can check Android [MediaPlayer API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) documentation

If you have more interested about the implementation, remember, we are open-source hehe, then take a while examining directly on the Titanium SDK repository -> [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=loadState)

--

Well, while the videoPlayer API has not been normalised (maybe will not), you can simple manage this issue creating a conditional flow, e.g:

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener('loadstate', function(evt){
    if(OS_IOS){...}
    else if(OS_ANDROID){...}
    else {...}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thanks **@Victor Casé** so much!  This can help me really!